# pip is not using extra index url defined in pip.conf

Tags: python, pip

I am using MacOS, and I created a pip.conf in ~/.pip. There is only one extral-index-url in this file, which looks like:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://[username]:[password]@artifactory
```

After that I tried to run `pip config list`, and I can see global.extra-index-url=https://[username]:[password]@artifactory in the terminal

However, when I try to use pip to install a package, it still doesn't check this URL. I can install the package by using `pip install <package> --extra-index-url https://[username]:[password]@artifactory`, but just curious why my pip.conf is not being used.

BTW I am using a virtual env when I run pip. I did copy pip.conf to the virtualenv folder, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I believe the `[install]` section is used when installing

Comment: @AnthonySottile `[global]` works for me; have been working for many years (we have a private index at the job); but we use `index` (for `pip search`) and `index-url`, not `extra-index-url`.

Comment: @phd a tool I maintain for work has both sections filled out with a comment `# otherwise pip may use the user's config` -- I suspect your `[global]`-only config gets overridden if someone has `~/.pip.conf` with `[install]` (which may be what OP has)

Comment: Quoting section [Configuration](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration): _On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` if directory `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip` exists else `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`._ Try copying the config file into `$HOME/.config/pip`.

Answer (score 5):

@hoefling's comment on the question is the answer I needed.  According to [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/), if a directory

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/
```

exists, that will shadow any

```
$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

file.  If ***that*** exists, it will shadow any

```
$HOME/.pip/pip.conf
```

file.  So investigate those locations in order, perhaps one of them is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for sanity.

If installing packages through `requirements.txt`, it is possible the [requirements file contains options for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#supported-options). This seems to take precedence over all the other options, including the command.

### requirements.txt

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
my-package==1.0.0
```